# What is the purpose of answering on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Why are there so many people who spend their time answering questions?

I thought that people were working here and receiving money for it, but I now know that nobody is being paid. So are they collecting reputation to show to e.g. future employers? Do they have nothing to do other than spending their time on Stack Overflow? Or are people just so helpful and are helping for no personal gain?

Comment: Can't speak for anyone else but I like to help people

Comment: Why must everything we do be for personal gain?

Comment: Its called building a community

Comment: The idea is get helped, and then help others. It is a comunity feedback

Comment: Learing is also the purpose. You can find very useful informations (f.e. in docs) when buidling full-featured answer .

Comment: I'd say for most of the reasons you mentioned (except getting paid). But, *"Or just people are so helpful and helping for no personal gain?"* There is much personal gain to be had in helping people on SO or anywhere. Besides the warm feeling you get in your tummy, I have learned a lot by answering questions because it made me think about what I was doing more and research to answer things I didn't know about.

Comment: Answering SO questions has helped me challenge my understanding, and made me look into new things. Not only can I help someone who's stuck, I can also learn from their challenges...

Answer (score 5):

This very question was actually part of the 2015 survey.  Of the choices provided, the most common reason for answering was to help a fellow programmer in need.  So yes, many people (64% of the respondents) answer questions to be helpful.

As for "collecting reputation to show it for future employer", only 20% selected the closest option to that sentiment (Demonstrating my expertise will benefit me).

If I recall correctly, this was a select one or more checkbox question so the groups of people are not mutually exclusive.  See [the results for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#community-answer).